# Voltage transition sense - rapid raise or fall

Tags: signal, level

Which means do we have to sense (relatively) fast voltage transition from **one** value to **another**. The exact point of **transition start**, **transition end** and the **intermediate state**. Which schematic gives us indication of these points.
And the special case: how do ICs sense voltage raise or fall?

**Edit**: Last edit turned question to the wrong direction, so I rolled it back and rephrased.

Comment: Do you mean sense an edge transition or the supply voltage?

Comment: Yes, I mean the edge - transition from low to high and vice versa.

Comment: @PF4Public, The title "Raise/Fall sense" is a little vague. Perhaps incorporate some of [ *Fake Name's* previous edits](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/8015/revisions) into the current version. Different MCUs (microcontrollers) will detect edges in various ways, not excluding any of those used in other ICs. You won't be able to copy their methods exactly using discrete components, but you can come close (or *mimic*).

Comment: But "Integrated Circuit" - is just like usual circuit, except it's extremely compact - "Integrated". So it employs usual elements with slightly different parameters. Well, until you're looking deep inside at microscopic effects. I agree, the title is not just "little vague" - it ambiguous :( I'm thinking about better replace.

Comment: You rolled back all my clarifications: **MCUs are a type of IC**, edge-trigging is used in all of them. Furthermore, sense is a very inaccurate description. The term "Edge-Triggering" **specifically refers** to exactly what you are describing. It is **the correct term** for what you are asking about.

Comment: @"But "Integrated Circuit" - is just like usual circuit, except it's extremely compact" - Well, what do you think MCUs are made of? Pixie dust and ground up unicorns?

Comment: @inaccurate - "The exact point of transition start, transition end and the intermediate state." Logic compares two values. The question is to find out dV/dt - it's not logical job. Is there any difference: V1==V2 and dV/dt>0?    
@MCU vs IC - doesn't matter, but if you insist. This way better?

Comment: Logic, as implemented in just about everything, is fundamentally analog. However, under certain circumstances, much of the analog nature can be simplified away. When I say logic, I am not referring to the simplified version.

Comment: It seems to me that we have a language gap here. Reading your comments, are you trying to ask what happens with logic devices when you have a very slowly transitioning, or even static intermediate signal on an input to a logic gate?

Comment: "are you trying to ask..." - No.

Comment: If that's not what you are trying to ask, I'm at a loss for what you are talking about.

Answer (score 5):

See Schmitt Trigger - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_trigger basically it's an amplifier circuit with positive feedback.

Comment: by basically, you mean it is an amplifier circuit with positive feedback.

Comment: @Kortuk yes, basically :p

Comment: your response just made my day.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends how far down you want to go. Keep in mind that every MCU that you will use is composed entirely of simple elements. Specifically, you will find transistors, capacitors, resistors, and diodes in every microcontroller and microprocessor since they stopped using vacuum tubes.

Without getting into digital logic fundamentals, a MCU can tell if an input changes by storing the digital value of a pin (1 or 0), and then comparing that stored value to the current pin value. The logical comparison is typically an exclusive-or.

You could make a very simple edge-detection circuit by using a resistor and capacitor in series to store the input voltage. Then measure the voltage difference between the capacitor and the input - if the difference is close to zero, then there has not been a change. If the difference is large, then the input has just changed.

Comment: [Here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/TSPC_FF_R.png);now we've gotten into digital logic fundamentals. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the insistence on using "MCUs" instead of "ICs". **MCUs are ICs**, and many ICs also have digital inputs. Furthermore, a MCU is basically just a specialty IC, and you can actually make a MCU out of a bunch of ICs.

The behavior of the inputs and outputs of a Schmitt trigger are thus:
[image]
Both axes are in voltage. ([Shamelessly pillaged from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger))

As you can see, the Schmitt-Trigger is specifically designed to *not have* an "intermediate state".

The "transition start, transition end and the intermediate state" are all part dependent, and there is no blanket answer. Read the datasheets for your part for the answer.

Here is a simulation of how edge triggering works at the logic-level:

http://www.play-hookey.com/digital/rs_nand_flip-flop.html

[vicatcu](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/771/vicatcu) has already covered the analog underpinning to building a schmitt trigger.

---

Interestingly enough, for logic devices without buffered/schmitt-trigger inputs, if you wrap negative feedback around the device, you can actually use it in an "analog mode", kind of like an amplifier.

It's not a good idea, though, and it may damage some parts. Also, there may be wide variations between parts from the same manufacturer, since analog performance is not specified or controlled.

Comment: *not have an "intermediate state"*. My question demands to feel that state, notice that at last.

Comment: I would call an MCU the opposite of specialty IC. You make an IC that can be programmed to do many different things so that the company can fabricate one chip for many many different applications.

Comment: A MCU is a specialty IC which implements a very complicated, specialty logic system which, when fed specific sequences of bits, can do many different things. It's still very specialized, and very much an IC. The *applications* may be general in nature, but the hardware is specialized.